# Submitting a form without action or method or any other javascript code

Tags: php, wordpress, html

A friend asked me add pattern code to prevent typing email ids and phone numbers, on his WP template site.

As i have added the pattern code to the input field, it still accepts email ids and numbers.

So, i figured that may be the form submit php code got some changes needed. but trickily his form tag doesn't have any action tag,. it just have form ID.

I don't know what to do. I just need to make the pattern work in the input field to prevent email id's and numbers.

the code goes as:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-9">

                <div class="message-entry">

                    <form id="message_reply_form">

                        <div class="form-group" >       
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" class="form-control mb-10" placeholder="<?php esc_html_e( 'Your Message', 'extretion' ); ?>" name="reply_message" pattern="^(?!.*([a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)).(?:\b\d{10,11}\b)[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"  >
                        </div>

                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm reply_message_btn" value="<?php esc_html_e( 'Reply', 'extretion' ); ?>">


                    </form>             

                </div>

            </div>
```

Any help is appreciated..

[network screenshot at the time of message submit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjtPC.png)

Comment: Use your inbuilt debug tools on a browser to navigate and find the class that calls message_reply_form. Maybe there's a bit of javascript creating the elements

Comment: You don't want people to enter emails?

Comment: Yes.. And numbers too

Answer (score 1):

In HTML5, the action attribute is no longer required.

[source](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_action.asp)

if I remember correctly, it defaults to current page. This is why the form is still submitted.

Comment: If i remember correct this is not an HTML5 feature, also in previous versions when missing the action the submit is in the same url.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried giving a action attribute to your form?

```
<form action='your/url'>
  The body of your form
</form>
```

Comment: No, i dont need to give it an action attribute cause without it , it is being submitted. and i dont know how.;..

Comment: it is submitting through ajax, check your browser network tab, and the url on which request is going on, also share the network tab screen shot while hitting the submit btn.

Comment: @MuhammadAkberKhan i have added the network tab screen shot of the page at the time of message submit..

Comment: there is on request in your network tab, something like ?reply=2243, click on this and again share the request details

Comment: @MuhammadAkberKhan On clicking on the ?reply=2243 it shows the html code for the existing message page.. Should copy paste that